# How to sort using 'key': C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, key

I am learning C. I have created a program to count frequency of words from a text file.
My struct contains three keys (frequency, word, nextLink).

The thing is I have sorted array of structs using key, but have no idea how to go about this one. Any guidance, links will be great.

I am providing my arrayOfStructs sort code

```
void sortArray(int array[], int count)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < count; ++j)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                temp =  array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would this be the possible way to sort LinkedList

```
void sortList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *i, *j, *temp;

    for (i = head; i != NULL ; i->next)
    {
        for (j = head->next; j != NULL; j->next)
        {
            if (head->frequency < head->next->frequency)
            {
                temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                head->next = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Node
{
    int frequency;
    char word[50];
    struct Node *next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `i = i->next` instead of `i->next` and `j = j->next` instead of `j->next`.

```
void sortList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *i, *j, *temp;

    for (i = head; i != NULL ; i = i->next) // i = i->next
    {
        for (j = head->next; j != NULL; j = j->next) // j = j->next
        {
            if (head->frequency < head->next->frequency)
            {
                temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                head->next = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the reason of negative feedback? :O